# My form is not being validated on submit with this code in Jquery. Can't figure out where the issue is

Tags: jquery

```
$(function()
{

   $('.submit-btn').click(function(event)
    {
      //Prevent form submission

     event.preventDefault();
     var inputs = $('input');
     var isError = false;

     //Remove old errors
     $('.input-frame').removeClass('error');
     $('.error-data').remove();

      //Validating data entered
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) 
            {
                var input = inputs[i];
                if ($(input).hasClass('required') && !validateRequired($(input).val())) 
                           {
                              addErrorData($(input), "This is a required field");
                              isError = true;
                            }

                if ($(input).hasClass('number') && !validateNumber($(input).val())) 
                            {
                               addErrorData($(input), "This field can only contain numbers");
                               isError = true;
                             }
                if ($(input).hasClass('credit-card') && !validateCreditCard($(input).val())) 
                             {
                               addErrorData($(input), "Invalid credit card number");
                               isError = true;
                              }
                if ($(input).hasClass('date') && !validateDate($(input).val())) 
                              {
                                addErrorData($(input), "Invalid date     provided");
                                isError = true;
                               }
              }
if (isError === false) 
{
//No errors, submit the form
$('#webForm').submit();

});

  });
function validateRequired(value) 
{
      if (value == "") return false;
            return true;
}

function validateNumber(value) 
{
     if (value != "") 
       {
         return !isNaN(parseInt(value, 10)) && isFinite(value);
         //isFinite, in case letter is on the end
       }
return true;
}

function addErrorData(element, error) 
{
element.parent().addClass("error");
element.after("<div class='error-data'>" + error + "</div>");
}
```

//Validating Credit Card number

```
  function validateCreditCard(value) 
    {
         if (value != "") 
         {
           return /^(?:4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?|5[1-5][0-9]
           {14}|6(?:011|5[0-9][0-9])[0-9]{12}|3[47][0-9]{13}|3(?:0[0-5]|[68]
           [0-9])[0-9]{11}|(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11})$/.test(value);
         }
    return true;
    }
```

Comment: When you step through the code in a debugger, where and how specifically does it fail?

Comment: you just have code here, you don't even have a statement of the issue.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate a from you need to bind to the `.submit()` event. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2yuucscn/

In the example when the submit button is clicked the submit event is raised. If the form is not validated then you prevent the default of the event to occur. In this case you stop the form from posting.